# Did 'apricus' undergo antiphrasis?

Tags: etymology, french

> #### Etymology [ [of (French verb) 'abrier'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrier#French) ]
>
> From [Middle French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French_language), from [Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French_language) *[abrier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrier#Old_French)* (“**to cover**”),
> itself mostly likely from [Late Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Latin) *[aprīcāre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricare)*,
> from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[aprīcārī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricari)*, present active infinitive of *[aprīcor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricor)* (“warm in the sun”),
> from *[aprīcus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricus#Latin)* (“sunny”).
> The form *abrier* may have been of southern French origin, possibly via Old Provençal *[abriar](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=abriar&action=edit&redlink=1)* (cf. the dialectal French form *[avrier](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=avrier&action=edit&redlink=1)*). Compare [Occitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_language), [Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language), [Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language) and [Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_language) *[abrigar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrigar#Portuguese)*.

#### Etymology [ [of (Latin adjective) 'apricus'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricus#Latin) ]

> From [Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin) *[*aperīcus](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/apericus&action=edit&redlink=1)*, from *[aperiō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aperio#Latin)* (“**to open**”).

1. Because the bolded are antonyms, is the semantic change [antiphrasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Types)?
2. If so, what might've caused the antiphrasis? What underlies 'open' and 'cover'?

I can divine 1 possibility: People trying to avoid something warmed in the sun, may cover that something (e.g. themselves if they're sunbathing. They probably didn't use umbrellas back then.).

Comment: «ABRIER v. tr. est issu (xiiie s.) du latin apricare « réchauffer au soleil », de apricus « ensoleillé », rapproché de apertus « ouvert », mais sans rapport réel, et donc d’origine obscure» (Dictionnaire historique de la langue française 2017).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this etymological dictionary of the cognate Spanish *abrigar*, the meaning of *"to protect against the wind"* was already attested in 4th century AD Latin.

> ABRIGAR, del lat. <sub><sup>APRĪCARE</sup></sub> 'calentar con el calor del sol', <sup><sub>*I.*</sub></sup><sup><sup>a</sup></sup> *doc.:* Berceo.
>
> La ac. 'proteger contra el viento' ya se halla en en el latín de Paladio (S. IV d. C.: Cabrera). Cuervo, *Dicc.* I, 62-64; Cej. IV, § 73.
>
> D<sub><sup>ERIV.</sup></sub> *Abrigo* [*Fn. Gonz.*] (postverbal de *abrigar*); el adj. ant. *abrigo* 'abrigado', en Berceo y en Martín Pérez de Ayala (1566: *Mod. Philol.* XXIV, 358) es el lat. <sub><sup>APRĪCUS</sup></sub> 'soleado', posteriormente sustituído por '*abrigaño*' [Nebr. *Abrigaños* «lugares guardados del viento», en el vocabulario de med. S. XV. *RFE* XXXV, 336]. *Abrigadal* 'abrigadero' ast. (V). *Desabrigar* [1455 (*BHisp.* LVIII, 85); Nebr.].

- [*Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispánico*](https://www.scribd.com/document/157203089/Diccionario-Critico-Etimologico-castellano-A-CA-Corominas-Joan-pdf), Joan Corominas

Wiktionary [suggests](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrigo#Etymology_5) this is via extending the meaning *"sunny"* to ***"that which wards off the cold"***.

---

Notably, in French (and most other Romance languages) there is a doublet of verbs with contrasting definitions, depending on whether the term came via *aprīcāre* or not:

- `Latin` [*aperīre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aperio#Latin) ("to uncover, open")

  - `Spanish` *abrir* ("to open")
  - `Vulgar Latin` **operīre*

    - `Old French` *ovrir* ("to open")

      - `French` ***ouvrir* ("to open")**
    - `Latin` [*aprīcus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apricus#Latin)

      - `Latin` *aprīcārī* ("warm in the sun")

        - `Late Latin` *aprīcāre*

          - `French` ***abrier* ("to cover")**
          - `Spanish` *abrigar* ("to cover")
- `Latin` [*operīre*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/operio#Latin) ("to cover, shut")

  - `Latin` *cooperīre* ("to cover completely")

    - `Spanish` *cubrir* ("to cover")
    - `Old French` *covrir*

      - `French` ***couvrir* ("to cover")**

---

It is interesting that *operīre* ("to cover") seems to have influenced the form of the *aperīre* ("to open") descended verbs of many Gallo-Romance languages (see column 3 below); while the cognate *abrigar/abrier* (retaining a similar form to *aperīre*) has flipped in meaning to "to cover" (column 4):

```
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
|                |   "To open"      |   "To open"   |  "To cover"  |   "To cover"       |
|   Language     | (via aperīre)    | (via aperīre, |(via aperīre, | (via aperīre,      |
|                |                  |     *operīre) |     aprīcāre)|     *operīre,      |
|                |                  |               |              |    cooperīre)      |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Fala           | abril            | -             | ?            | ?                  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Old Portuguese | abrir            | -             | abrigar      | cobrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Portuguese     | abrir            | -             | abrigar      | cobrir, acobertar  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Galician       | abrir            | -             | abrigar      | cubrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Asturian       | abrir            | -             | abrigar      | cubrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Spanish        | abrir            | -             | abrigar      | cubrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Aragonese      | -                | ubrir         | abrigar      | cubrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Old Provençal  | -                | obrir         | ?            | cobrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Catalan        | -                | obrir         | abrigar      | cobrir             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Occitan        | -                | obrir, dobrir | abrigar      | cobrir, cubrir     |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Old French     | -                | ovrir, olvrir,| abrier       | covrir, cuvrir     |
|                |                  | ouvrir, uvrir |              |                    |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| French         | -                | ouvrir        | abrier       | couvrir            |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Norman         | -                | ouvri (Jersey)| ?            | ?                  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
|Franco-Provençal| -                | uvrir         | ?            | ?                  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Italian        | aprire           | -             | ?            | coprire            |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Neapolitan     | arapì, arape     | -             | ?            | ?                  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Venetian       | averzir, avèrzer,| -             | ?            | covrir, covèrzar,  |
|                | avèrxer, vèrzer, |               |              | coèrxar, coèrxer,  |
|                | vèrzar, verxar   |               |              | covèrxer, cuèrxer, |
|                |                  |               |              | cuèrzar            |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Sicilian       | apriri, iàpriri, | -             | ?            | ?                  |
|                | jàpriri, gràpiri |               |              |                    |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Sardinian      | abbèrrere,       | -             | ?            | cobèrrere, cobèrri,|
|                |abèrriri, apèrrere|               |              |cobèrriri, copèrrere|
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Friulian       | avierzi, aviergi,| -             | ?            | cuvierzi, cuviergi |
|                | vierzi, viergi   |               |              |                    |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Romansch       | avrir, arver     | -             | ?            | cuvrir, cuvierer,  |
|                |                  |               |              | cuvreir            |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Dalmatian      | apiar, aprer     | -             | ?            | coprer             |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Aromanian      | apir, apiriri    | -             | ?            | acoapir, acupiriri |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Romanian       | ?                | -             | ?            | acoperi            |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Walloon        | drovi            | -             | ?            | ?                  |
+----------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
```